# How to check in UPDATE Trigger if record has really changed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have a SQL Server 2012 UPDATE Trigger which occurs when data is updated within a table in the database (Microsoft Project Server Database) :)

I am using the following statement to get the updated element from the table within the Trigger

```
SELECT @dataId = INSERTED.Id FROM INSERTED;
```

But the problem is due to the behaviour of the Microsoft Project Server, that it updates ALL Tasks within a Project even if only one task was changed (each Task is one record in database).

I know that i can get the id of the item which should be updated, but i dont know how i could compare the to updated row with the data which is still in the database within the UPDATE Trigger?

Comment: The first issue I see here is that you are using scalar values in your trigger. This is a huge red flag that you are assuming there will only ever be a single value in inserted. This is not how triggers work. They fire once per operation, not once per row. Your trigger needs to be set based. If you want to check the current value against the new value you would join inserted to your base table. If the values are different, it has changed.

Comment: Thank you Sean. But a) how could a best practice look like? b) I need to compare more than only one single field, lets say 7-8 fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get what rows actually changed, then use this inside the trigger

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
  INSERTED I
  JOIN
  DELETED D ON I.KeyCol = D.KeyCol
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT I.Col1, I.Col2, I.Col3, I.Col4 ...
     INTERSECT
     SELECT D.Col1, D.Col2, D.Col3, D.Col4 ...
     )
```

The [NOT EXISTS..INTERSECT deals with NULLs](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx) etc for you already